# Alternative Widget for Django Admin Choice Field Select with Many Entries?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a model with many country fields and each is a choice field wit list of countries.

The issue is that there's a lot of countries! So each choice field adds a lot of size and rendering time to the page to generate a select dropdown in django admin. (E.g. Making 5 of these read only brought down response time from 10s to 4s!)

I want to see if there's any alternatives known for handling choice field inputs. Since we use ISO-2 for countries, I want to avoid operators having to input values directly as they would not know them.

Ideally I was hoping for some sort of search or select pop-up similar to what happens with `raw_id_fields`. That way a select list is only generated when needed, but so far havent found

Answer (score 0):

You may try django-jet package or one of its forks. It is fully rewritten django-admin template, and it supports typing search for model choice fields. Or try looking for another package in [django packages](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/admin-interface/)